# In using a Koine lexicon, does only the first entry count?

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches, translation-philosophy

It has been suggested on another site that only the first entry of a Koine lexicon "counts". In this example of neo-Platonism, the first lexeme matches the "Ideal Form" which in this case is an **objective true definition of a word** with the other entries the same meaning but in a different form, OR, simply false definitions.

Is the first entry of a Koine lexicon the "Ideal Form" of which the other entries act as instances?

Or is it within the realm of possibility that words break from this "principle" and sometimes have multiple distinct usages?

Comment: Sounds like nonsense to me. The kind of nonsense that leads to so-called "mechanical translations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language isn't defined by the dictionary; the dictionary describes the language, which is naturally subject to [ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy) – not only in [words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) (and [homographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph) in written language), but also in morphology and [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity), which can allow for multiple ways to parse a sentence.

The first entry in a lexicon can hardly be an "objective true definition of a word," since it was placed there as an editorial decision made centuries after the era the language was spoken. Furthermore, the fact that the editors of the lexicon added more entries clearly demonstrates that they believed the word to carry more than one meaning.

To illustrate the consequences of always interpreting a word by its first entry in the dictionary, we can take the first sentence of your question:

> It has been suggested on another **site** that only the first **entry** of a Koine lexicon "**counts**".

[**site**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/site#Etymology_2)

> The place where anything is fixed; situation; local position

[**entry**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entry#English)

> The act of entering.

[**count**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/count#English)

> To recite numbers in sequence.

Clearly the sentence meant none of these.

Comment: Nicely organized and illustrated answer. Thanks.